# How to improve the speed of comparing strings in lists(millions of data)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

The code that will compare city and sort to file

```
for city in uniqueCity:
    file = open(city+".txt","a+")
    for data in salesData:
        if data[2] == city:
            file.write(",".join(data).replace(","," "))
            file.write("\n")
    file.close()
```

Comment: Please edit your post and format the code

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark it? How slow it is? Also use bold text where it's not really necessary is discouraged.

Comment: What is the content of `uniqueCity`?

Comment: The content of uniqueCity is a set that contains non-repeating city name.

Comment: How is it generated? From `data`?

Comment: The script takes around 4 mins to run this block of code. The problem should be the if data[2] == city part. It takes too much time to execute.

Comment: No, the uniqueCity is generated using other function beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is slow because the algorithm is slow.

As written, for each `city` (loop `len(uniqueCity)` times), it have to loop over all of `salesData` (`len(salesData)` times), so the total number of comparison performed is `len(uniqueCity) * len(salesData)`. In this case (`city` is a `str`, I guess), you can do better, because strings are hashable.

```python
groupedSalesData = {city:[] for city in uniqueCity}

for data in salesData:
    city = data[2]
    if city in groupedSalesData:
        groupedSalesData[city].append(data)

for city, dataEntries in groupedSalesData.items():
    file = open(city + ".txt", "a+")
    for data in dataEntries:
        file.write(",".join(data).replace(","," "))
        file.write("\n")
    file.close()
```

As you can see, the complexity of this algorithm is just `len(uniqueCity) + len(salesData)` (assuming `data` takes `O(1)` times for copying, and because operations on Python `dict` should be `O(1)`), which is much better.

Comment: (I'm welcome to any constructive criticism, so if you downvoted my answer, you may also want to left a comment explaining how can the answer be made better, so I can improve my answer)